# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' (But it is installed)

Tags: python, psycopg2, tweepy

I've been stuck on a part of a Udemy course. Even the (very helpful) tutor on there has run of ideas. When I try and run my script I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

I've done `pip install psycopg2` and `pip install psycopg2-2.8.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`. Both result in 'requirement already satisfied'. I tried CTRL+SHIFT+P, Select Interpreter, and got the same problem with all of the three options. Only difference is Python3.8.0 gives me a `Unable to import 'psycopg2' pylint(import-error) [1,1]` error as well.

```
C:\Python\Database>pip install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in c:\users\jeff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.8.4)

C:\Python\Database>script1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Database\script1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

### Edit

I still can't figure this out. And now I just got the same problem with Tweepy. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'` after I'd just successfully installed it. And similar error in the problems tab on VSC `Unable to import 'tweepy' pylint(import-error) [1,1]`.

Comment: See https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2018/02/08/psycopg-274-released/. You may install `psycopg2-binary`

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Psycopg project has modified the way they distribute the package. Starting from version 2.8.0, `psycopg2` wheel on Pypi is a source distribution. To get the same package you used to install, you have to

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Explanations can be found in [psycopg-2.7.4 release note](http://psycopg.org/articles/2018/02/08/psycopg-274-released):

> The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: </docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried this already and got 'Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in c:\users\jeff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.8.4)'

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by installing `psycopg2` using PyCharm UI as follows :

1. Go to Current interpreter at the bottom of the window
   [Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjDSt.png)
2. Interpreter Settings
   [Interpreter Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYVZ3.png)
3. Press (+) to add a package
   [Add package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Urn.png)
4. Type `psycopg2` on the search bar and press Install Package at the botton
   [Install psycopg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ct3M.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to first install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2
```

Now run

```
pip install pyschopg2
```

Comment: I got 
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
Tried it without sudo and got  
'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Oh! Sorry that was for ubuntu. For windows try `conda install build-dep python-psycopg2` and then the second command

Comment: Yes, because sudo or apt-get are Debian/Linux commands, and you are working on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: I got this.... Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - build-dep
  - python-psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is check is where the psycopg2 module is installed:

```
$ pip show psycopg2
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.9.6
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: https://psycopg.org/
Author: Federico Di Gregorio
Author-email: fog@initd.org
License: LGPL with exceptions
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

And ensure that the directory named in `Location:` is on your path:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.11', '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/home/razzi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.11/dist-packages']
```

If the path is missing, you can add it to your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or modify [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules). Ideally you wouldn't have to do these; they may be indicative of a faulty install or a misconfigured environment, but they might be a useful workaround.